# Spring MVC 3: open ModelAndView in a new tab

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

I am submitting a form in jsp. After running the underlying logic spring mvc returns view.

There are 2 conditions. i.e.

```
if(condition1){
    mav = new ModelAndView("jspPageName1");
    return mav;
}else{
    mav = new ModelAndView("jspPageName2");
    return mav;
}
```

I want **jspPageName1** to be open in a new tab and **jspPageName2** will be opened in the same tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to *browser tabs* it can't be done from Spring.

You can on a link level specify `<a href="#" target="_blank"/>` to trigger a link opening in a new tab/window. Remember though, a users local browser configuration always has precedence of any server settings.

Comment: if I can't do it in spring then how can I handle this in jsp? I am submitting a form. <form action="someaction"> and I show different views based on the form parameters.

Comment: As I said, two links, one with `target="_bank"` and one without.